# How to generate the same image with the function of imshow() from matplotlib(python) and imshow() in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

For the same matrix, the image generated by the function imshow() from matplotlib and matlab is different. how to change some parameters of imshow() in matplotlib can get same result in matlab

```
%matlab
img = 255*rand(101);
img(:,1:50)=3;
img(:,52:101)=1;
img(:,51)=2;
trans_img=imtranslate(img,[3*cos(pi/3),3*sin(pi/3)]);
imshow(trans_img)
```

[This is an image generated by matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK0as.jpg)

```
#python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mlab.releases import latest_release as mtl #call matlab function

img = 255 * np.random.uniform(0, 1, (101, 101))
img[:, 51:101] = 1 
img[:, 0:50] = 3
img[:, 50] = 2
trans_img = mtl.imtranslate(img, [[3*math.cos(math.pi/3),3*math.sin(math.pi/3)]] 
i = plt.imshow(trans_img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show(i)
```

[This is an image generated by matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXspN.png)

The trans_img matrix is the same in both cases, but the images in matlab and python are different

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about what image you're generating and what exactly is different between the two versions.

Comment: Sorry, I have update some details of my code to make this question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have an up-to-date enough version of Matlab that has the `imtranslate` function, but thankfully the `image` package in Octave does, which I'm sure is equivalent. Equally, I will be using the `oct2py` module instead of `mlab` as a result, for python to access the `imtranslate` function from octave within python.

Octave code:

```
img = 255*rand(101);
img(:,1:50)=3;
img(:,52:101)=1;
img(:,51)=2;
trans_img = imtranslate(img, 3*cos(pi/3),3*sin(pi/3));
imshow(trans_img, [min(trans_img(:)), max(trans_img(:))])
```

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from oct2py import octave
octave.pkg('load','image');  # load image pkg for access to 'imtranslate'
img = 255 * np.random.uniform(0, 1, (101, 101))
img[:, 51:101] = 1 
img[:, 0:50] = 3
img[:, 50] = 2
trans_img = octave.imtranslate(img, 3*math.cos(math.pi/3), 3*math.sin(math.pi/3))
i = plt.imshow(trans_img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show(i)
```

Resulting image (identical) in both cases:

[image]

My only comment on why you may have been seeing the discrepancy, is that I *did* specify the `min` and `max` values in `imshow`, to ensure appropriate intensity scaling. Equally you could have just used `imagesc(trans_img)` instead (I actually prefer this). I didn't specify such limits explicitly in python for `plt.imshow` ... perhaps it performs scaling by default.

Also, your code has a small bug; in the octave version of `imtranslate` at least, the function takes 3 arguments, not two. (Also, your original code has an unbalanced bracket).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have update some codes of this question. The only thing make me confused is the imshow() of matlab and python give different image result for same matrix.

Comment: Updated answer as per updated question. :)
Also, forgive my being rude, but, the fact that I had to answer with an oversimplistic 'bait' answer first, in order to coax the 'real' question, is a bit of a waste of time for everyone involved. Please do your best to ask appropriate,  specific questions like your updated version from the  beginning next time :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a problem, Because I just want to change some parameter of imshow() in matplotlib to achieve the same result in Matlab with imshow(trans_img).don't need to change any parameter like the code : imshow(trans_img, [min(trans_img(:)), max(trans_img(:))]). Really sorry about that I'm using my phone to comment, not convient to set the code in appropriate format

Comment: What I'm saying above is that `imshow(trans_img) % in matlab` is showing the *wrong* result because it doesn't take scaling into account. Are you asking me how to replicate the *wrong* result using matplotlib?

Comment: Actually, even if I remove the line of code-function imtranslate() in both matlab and python, just imshow(img) in Matlab and python, it still not same image.

Comment: Yes, because python seems to perform scaling by default, like I said.
I bet that if you used `imagesc` in matlab instead of `imshow` you would get the same result you get in python with `plt.imshow`

Comment: I totally agree with you, I also notice this problem. I want to use the imshow() function to generate a image patch to test edge detection algorithm which I have done in matlab before. But I want to try the algorithm in python. with the different image, I can not easily to compare the result.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is. If you want to ensure that the images are displayed in the same range in both matlab and python, then simply be specific about the intensity range you want to inspect in both. To specify in matlab it would be as above with imshow, to specify in python it would be: `plt.imshow(trans_img, cmap='gray', vmin = np.min(trans_img), vmax = np.max(trans_img));`