# How to run Octave-4.4 exe from python?

Tags: python-3.x, octave

I have searched about this topic but I can not find a solution. There are some libraries oc2py and pytave However, I am newbie about this. I have a batch file, I want to run it from python:

```
set SCRIPTS_DIR=(path of neccassary *.m files)

set OCTAVE_COMMAND="cd(getenv('SCRIPTS_DIR')); 
set OCTAVE_COMMAND=%OCTAVE_COMMAND%CORE_LEVEL_PREPROCESS;
set OCTAVE_COMMAND=%OCTAVE_COMMAND%STARTUP_HYDROLOGY_MODULE;
set OCTAVE_COMMAND=%OCTAVE_COMMAND%CORE_LEVEL_OUTPUT_MANAGER;"

start octave-cli.exe --eval %OCTAVE_COMMAND%
```

`CORE_LEVEL_PREPROCESS`, `STARTUP_HYDROLOGY_MODULE`, `CORE_LEVEL_OUTPUT_MANAGER` are names of *.m files in `SCRIPTS_DIR`.

I guess I should give that line `start octave-cli.exe --eval %OCTAVE_COMMAND%` to python but I can not do that.

Comment: You're not being very clear what you want to do exactly, but here's some links to other questions where I answered about how to use oct2py for particular cases. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543580/4183191 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45526673/4183191 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547151/4183191 https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387123/4183191

Answer (score 0):

If this is a batch file, then try:

```
import os
os.system("D:\\xxx1\\xxx2XMLnew\\otr.bat ")
```

Failing that, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469301/run-a-bat-file-using-python-code) suggests

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("batch.bat", cwd=r"C:\Path\to\batchfolder")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: I don't want to run batch file I can also do that I want to use python with oc2py or pytave or whatever